# Concerning the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sin nx$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, divergent-series

I recently came across this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186308/sum-of-series-sin-x-sin-2x-sin-3x-cdots) and I posted an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186308/sum-of-series-sin-x-sin-2x-sin-3x-cdots/850197#850197). It has been pointed out that my answer is incorrect. I cannot work out what is wrong with my reasoning. The answer I gave corresponds with the Abel and Cesaro sum, so perhaps $\sum$ is not the usual summation operator? Am I correct in asserting that if $x$ is in the upper half-plane, i.e., $\textbf{I}[x] > 0$, then $|e^{ix}| < 1$ and consequently
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty e^{inx} = \frac{e^{ix}}{1 - e^{ix}},$$
or is my argument flawed? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ah, no, the problem is when you assume $1-e^{-ix}$ is the conjugate of $1-e^{ix}$. It is only the conjugate when $x$ is real...

Comment: You never have $|e^{ix}|<1$. Because $|e^{ix}|=1$ for every $x$.

Comment: Also, the imaginary part of $e^{inx}$ is not $\sin nx$ when $x$ is not real.

Comment: @Yotas follow the link, he assumes the imaginary part of $x$ is positive...

Comment: @YotasTrejos You are wrong. Like I said, $|e^{ix}| < 1$ when $x$ is in the upper half-plane.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you assume that $x$ is not real, the imaginary part of $e^{inx}$ is not $\sin nx$.

Also, when computing the conjugate if $1-e^{ix}$, you don't get $1-e^{-ix}$ when $x$ is non-real, but rather $$1-e^{-i\bar x}$$

Comment: I know that $1 - e^{-ix}$ is not the conjugate of $1 - e^{ix}$. I simply multiplied and divided by it to find the real and imaginary part of $e^{ix}/(1 - e^{ix})$. Is this not permissible?

Comment: That's wrong, because the denominator needs to be real for that trick to work, and the only way for that trick to work is if you multiply by the conjugate. $(1-e^{ix})(1-e^{-ix})$ is not real when $x$ is not real, so how does that help you?

Comment: I see. You are right. I think this answers my question. However, I find it rather strange that my reasoning lead to the correct Abel and/or Cesaro sum.

Comment: I have a feeling about the Abel summability of a general power series on its boundary when the function has an analytic continuation on that boundary point. But that's just a gut feeling.

Comment: Thanks again. By the way, I have a feeling that there is not closed formula for the real and imaginary part of $e^{ix}/(1 - e^{ix})$ when $x$ is in the upper half-plane. Am I correct?